# Leaflet - custom tile layer - get lat long coordinates

Tags: leaflet, maps, geo

My requirement is be able to call an api which returns me GeoJson - this api requires the bounding box in lat/long coordinates. I would like to be able to have this api called for each tile but am stuck trying to convert the `L.Coords` x,y,z values to bounds.

I would have thought this would be a common use case - is there another way I should be approaching this problem?

Code demonstrates my approach.

```
L.TileLayer.Custom = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: (coords: L.Coords) => {

        const bounds = coords?.getBounds();

        const geometry = {
            ymin: bounds?.getSouth(),
            xmin: bounds?.getWest(),
            ymax: bounds?.getNorth(),
            xmax: bounds?.getEast()
        };

        // call api Api.call(geometry).then(...)
    },
});

L.tileLayer.custom = function () {
    return new L.TileLayer.Custom();
};

L.tileLayer.custom().addTo(map);
```

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L748

Comment: Thanks Ivan - so to confirm extending GridLayer is the correct way as it gives me acces to the private ```_tileCoordsToBounds``` method?

Comment: No - `TileLayer` already extends `GridLayer`, so you should be able to call `this._tileCoordsToBounds(...)`.

Comment: I have been scratching my head searching the internet for days over this - thank you.